# Reusing a UIViewController subclass I've made for very similar but not identical situations: recommended?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm still relatively new to iOS development and was wondering about whether or not it's a good practice to do that.

For example, let's say I have two different contexts in which I want to present identical/similar data in identical/similar ways, but there are some differences, maybe some different buttons from one context to another or different things I need to do to prepare the data. Should I just make multiple configuration methods in the same view controller and call whichever one as needed, or have two separate view controllers?

I'm heavily leaning toward the former being correct since it seems a lot more efficient and saves a lot of identical code, but I'd like some input from more experienced programmers just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create three view controllers: `SuperViewController`, `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` should be the subclasses of your `SuperViewController`. Then you should consider the following:

## Variables and Properties

Declare all the common variables between your view controllers in the `SuperViewController`.

Declare any view controller specific variables and properties within the appropriate view controller.

## Methods

As with properties, define any shared methods in your `SuperViewController` together with their implementation.

If you have methods which share some, **but not all** of their code between your view controllers do the following:

1) In your `SuperViewController` implement this method:

```
-(void)someSemiSharedMethod {
    // put the common code here
}
```

2) In your view controllers:

```
-(void)someSemiSharedMethod {
    // call the superclass' implementation of this method
    // to ensure that common code is executed
    [super someSemiSharedMethod];

    // now add any child controller specific code to this method below
}
```

This seams like the best approach for what you want to achieve. Let me know if you have some other questions or if this approach doesn't fully achieve what you want.

Comment: I agree. Using inheritance would be the proper way of handling this (though "parent" and "child" VCs may not be the best name, as they usually [mean something else in the iOS context](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)). By keeping them separate this way you make each controller slimmer, easier to test and maintain. Also, what differences (and common parts!) there are between them will become immediately obvious to whoever needs to read your code in the future.

Comment: @Gamma you are right, I should probably change the naming :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the parent superclass method that Andriy described, but there is another option.

Subclassing is very powerful, but sometimes hard to reason about. If there's a bug in one of the child view controllers, it can be hard to figure out where that bug really lies.

If the customisations to the view controller are small, you can express this using arguments to the constructor, for example:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSaveButton(BOOL)includeSaveButton;
```

Or, if you need to customise some behaviour, pass a block:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSaveAction:(void (^)(Person *))saveAction;
```

If the customisations are minimal, I find this to be a neater solution than subclassing.

---

**EDIT**: A side note, but @leiyun asked a great question about the BOOL flags - what if we want to choose between including button A and button B? Should we design an init method like this?

```
- (instancetype)initWithButtonA:(BOOL)includeA buttonB:(BOOL)includeB;
```

Well this is a great example of why BOOL flags should be avoided. If we call this method like `initWithButtonA:YES buttonB:YES`, then we're into undefined behaviour because we wanted to choose *between* those buttons.

So for this, define an options type.

```
typedef enum {
    MyViewControllerModeNoButtons,
    MyViewControllerModeButtonA,
    MyViewControllerModeButtonB
} MyViewControllerMode;

- (instancetype)initWithMode:(MyViewControllerMode)mode;
```

A guiding principle for interfaces like this is that there shouldn't be an incorrect way to call it. Also, this will better accommodate more options when you need a third button or an image view or something else!

Comment: Yep, this is also a good approach. All depends on the amount of customisation which is required

Comment: In regards to expressing a customization using arguments to the constructor, what's the best way to handle a situation where I either want button X or button Y?

It seems a bit awkward to do something like

"initWithXButton:(bool)includeXButton", and then include button Y if includeXButton is false.

Comment: Instead of using a BOOL you could also have specialised constructors, e.g. both a "initForContext1" and "initForContext2" method.

Comment: Ok, cool. I guess it's always better to specify differences in constructors. I was initially doing something like [vc configureForX] after doing [[vc alloc] init], which upon further reflection seems like pretty poor design.

Comment: @leiyun great question! I just edited my answer to provide my response.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake I want to also put forward what I would consider as a third option after Andriy's and joerick's answers, especially for the "*different things I need to do to prepare the data*"-scenario: actually using the same view controller class for both screens, but creating separate data source objects for each context that hold, prepare and provide the appropriate data.

Those data source objects could be simple NSObject subclasses, conforming to a protocol. For common ways of displaying data there are already predefined protocols for data sources, like *UITableViewDataSource* and *UICollectionViewDataSource*. If those don't suit your needs you can of course define your own protocol. The data source could be held by a view controller instance as a property, like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UITableViewDataSource> myDataSource;
```

You could "give" the appropriate data source to your view controller upon initialization, e.g.

```
-(instancetype)initWithDataSource: (id<UITableViewDataSource>) dataSource
```